# How to split cell contents from multiple columns into rows by delimeter?

Tags: excel, vba

The code I have takes cells containing the delimiter (; ) from a column, and creates new rows (everything except the column is duplicated) to separate those values.

What I have
[image]

I need this for multiple columns in my data, but I don't want the data to overlap (ex: for 3 columns, I want there to be only one value per row in those 3 columns). It would be ideal if I could select multiple columns instead of only one as my code does now.

What I want
[image]

```vb
Sub splitByCol()
    Dim r As Range, i As Long, ar
    Set r = Worksheets("Sheet").Range("J2000").End(xlUp)
    Do While r.Row > 1
        ar = Split(r.Value, "; ")
        If UBound(ar) >= 0 Then r.Value = ar(0)
        For i = UBound(ar) To 1 Step -1
            r.EntireRow.Copy
            r.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
            r.Offset(1).Value = ar(i)
        Next
        Set r = r.Offset(-1)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not a mistake in the picture showing what you want? I mean, in column be, shouldn't it be `Red` followed by `Blue`, instead of `Blue` - `Blue`... Should there be **more the two strings separated by ";"** in a cell? If yes, can you estimate a maximum?

Comment: @FaneDuru Hi, sorry yes that's a typo on my part. There can be more than 2 strings in a cell, but the maximum would probably be around 5.

Comment: I am not sure I correctly understood the splitting logic, only looking to your picture... What does the border lines after the third and sixth rows should mean? Are they there only to confuse as?

Comment: Please, test the code in my answer and send some feedback. It supposes that the border lines were only meant to confuse... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
    Dim a, x, e, i As Long, ii As Long, iii As Long, k As Long
    a = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ReDim b(1 To 1000, 1 To UBound(a, 2))
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        For ii = 2 To 3
            x = Split(a(i, ii), "; ")
            For Each e In x
                k = k + 1
                b(k, 1) = k
                b(k, 2) = IIf(ii = 2, e, Empty)
                b(k, 3) = IIf(ii = 3, e, Empty)
                b(k, 4) = a(i, 4)
            Next e
        Next ii
    Next i
    Range("A5").Resize(UBound(b, 1), UBound(b, 2)).Value = b
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go this way

```
Sub SplitByCol()

    With Worksheets("Sheet")
    
        With .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
            
            Dim firstColValues As Variant
                firstColValues = .Value

            Dim secondColValues As Variant
                secondColValues = .Offset(, 1).Value

            Dim thirdColValues As Variant
                thirdColValues = .Offset(, 2).Value
        
            .Offset(, -1).Resize(, 4).ClearContents
            
        End With
        
        Dim iRow As Long
            For iRow = LBound(firstColValues) To UBound(firstColValues)
            
                Dim currFirstColValues As Variant
                    currFirstColValues = Split(firstColValues(iRow, 1), "; ")
                Dim currSecondColValues As Variant
                    currSecondColValues = Split(secondColValues(iRow, 1), "; ")
                    
                        With .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1)
                            With .Resize(UBound(currFirstColValues) + 1)
                                .Value = currFirstColValues
                                .Offset(, 2).Value = thirdColValues(iRow, 1)
                            End With
                        End With
                        
                        With .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1)
                            With .Resize(UBound(currSecondColValues) + 1)
                                .Value = currSecondColValues
                                .Offset(, 1).Value = thirdColValues(iRow, 1)
                            End With
                        End With
                        
            Next
            
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Follow the code step by step by pressing F8 while the cursor is in any code line in the VBA IDE and watch what happens in the Excel user interface

EDIT

adding edited code for a more "parametric" handling by means of a helper function

```
Sub SplitByCol()

    With Worksheets("Sheet")
    
        With .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
            
            Dim firstColValues As Variant
                firstColValues = .Value
            Dim secondColValues As Variant
                secondColValues = .Offset(, 1).Value
            Dim thirdColValues As Variant
                thirdColValues = .Offset(, 2).Value
        
            .Offset(, -1).Resize(, 4).ClearContents
            
        End With
        
        Dim iRow As Long
            For iRow = LBound(firstColValues) To UBound(firstColValues)
            
                Dim currFirstColValues As Variant
                    currFirstColValues = Split(firstColValues(iRow, 1), "; ")
                Dim currSecondColValues As Variant
                    currSecondColValues = Split(secondColValues(iRow, 1), "; ")
                    
                     WriteOne .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1), _
                               currFirstColValues, thirdColValues(iRow, 1), _
                               -1, 2
                        
                     WriteOne .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1), _
                              currSecondColValues, thirdColValues(iRow, 1), _
                              1, 1
            Next
            
    End With
    
End Sub


Sub WriteOne(refCel As Range, _
             currMainColValues As Variant, thirdColValue As Variant, _
             mainValuesOffsetFromRefCel As Long, thirdColValuesOffsetFromRefCel As Long)

    With refCel.Offset(, mainValuesOffsetFromRefCel)
        With .Resize(UBound(currMainColValues) + 1)
            .Value = currMainColValues
            .Offset(, thirdColValuesOffsetFromRefCel).Value = thirdColValue
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, use the next code. It uses arrays and should be very fast for big ranges to be processed, working mostly in memory:

```
Sub testSplitInsert()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrSp, arrFin, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   arr = sh.Range("B1:D" & lastR).Value
   ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr) * 10, 1 To 3) 'maximum to keep max 10 rows per each case
   k = 1 'initialize the variable to load the final array
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        arrSp = Split(Replace(arr(i, 1)," ",""), ";") 'trim for the case when somebody used Red;Blue, instead of Red; Blue
        For j = 0 To UBound(arrSp)
            arrFin(k, 1) = arrSp(j): arrFin(k, 3) = arr(i, 3): k = k + 1
        Next j
        arrSp = Split(Replace(arr(i, 1)," ",""), ";")
        For j = 0 To UBound(arrSp)
            arrFin(k, 2) = arrSp(j): arrFin(k, 3) = arr(i, 3): k = k + 1
        Next j
   Next
   
   sh.Range("G1").Resize(k - 1, 3).Value = arrFin
End Sub
```

It processes the range in columns "B:D" and returns the result in columns "G:I". It can be easily adapted to process any columns range and return even  overwriting the existing range, but this should be done only after checking that it return what you need...